# Synonyms/Join with a string of words in Python

Tags: python, string, join, text

I want to use PyDictionary to find all the synonyms for each word in a string of text, and i want to return a concatenated version of the answers for each word in a string.  I know I need some sort of join statement, but haven't quite been able to work it out.  Answers so far have been helpful generally, but there is an additional complication.

When dictionary.synonyms(word) doesn't have any synonyms, it replies with "word has no Synonyms in the API" which it considers to be a list.  I get this error:

```
 <ipython-input-53-9f48f79fe623> in str_synonyms(string)
  3     newstring = ''
  4     for word in string:
  5         while dictionary.synonym(word).endswith("has no Synonyms in the API"):
  6             newstring += 'none'
  7         else:
```

when I add a filter to replace those instances with "none".

This is the latest iteration of the function:

```
 #Function to find synonyms for search terms
 def str_synonyms(string):
    newstring = ''
    for word in string:
        while dictionary.synonym(word).endswith("has no Synonyms in the API"):
            newstrong += none
        else:
            newstring += dictionary.synonym(word) 
    return newstring
```

Any additional help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you are not using the `join` function correctly, reminder that `str.join(list)` returns a string where each value in `list` is joined together by `str`

Comment: `dictionary.synonym(word)` returns a _list_ (of all the possible synonyms of `word`, I guess). So what would you want to append to `newstring` if there were more than one synonym? (BTW, this explains the `TypeError` exception).

Comment: i want to append all the synonyms. so if the synonyms of shower were "rain", "downpour", and "flood", I'd want those all comma separated in a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `string` argument is from words separated by spaces you can try this:

```
def str_synonyms(string):
    newstring_list = []
    for word in string.split():
        if dictionary.synonym(word):
            newstring_list.extend(dictionary.synonym(word))
    newstring = ', '.join(newstring_list)  
    return newstring
```

Comment: thanks! when i do that, it mostly works- but i end up with an error related to lists/strings due to the synonym function.  any ideas here? i've updated the code above.

Comment: @user2573355 I've edited the answer, does it work now?

Comment: getting closer!  that returns this error: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: #Function to find synonyms for search terms
def str_synonyms(string):
    newstring = ''
    for word in string:
        if type(dictionary.synonym(word)) == list:
            newstring += 'none'
        else:
            newstring += str(dictionary.synonym(word))
    return newstring

Comment: @user2573355 I've edited again the answer and this for me works.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the [github sources](https://github.com/geekpradd/PyDictionary/blob/master/PyDictionary/core.py) linked from PyPI, and it seems the static method for synonyms returns a list if it succeeds, but prints an error and returns nothing (None) otherwise.

I'd think this code would work for you:

```
def get_synonym_search(word):

    synlist = dictionary.synonym(word)
    synlist = [] if not synlist else synlist

    synlist = [word] + synlist

    search = "(" + " OR ".join(synlist) + ")"
    return search
```